# Accessing function results from another function?

Tags: javascript

I have these functions

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var img = new Image;
            img.src = reader.result;

            var imgwidth = img.width;
            var imgheight = img.height;
            console.log(imgwidth);
            console.log(imgheight);

            $('#imgcrop').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.crop').Jcrop({

                onSelect: updateCoords,
                boxWidth: 300,
                boxHeight: 300,
                onChange: showPreview,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                bgOpacity:   .4,
                setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]
            });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
    console.log(this);
    readURL(this);
});

function updateCoords(c) {
    console.log(c);
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
}

function showPreview(coords) {
    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * imgwidth) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * imgheight) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
}
```

And I need to access imgwidth and imgheight from the file reader function to use in the showpreview function, but I'm having trouble with the scope of those functions. How can I access these values, or at least pass them as parameters to use in the other function?

Thanks!

Comment: declare a global variable, outside of the functions.

Comment: Is it ok to do that? Is it good practice to have global variables? Does this case justify the use of global variables? I'm sorry, I'm a JS newbie and I've been told not to pollute the global scope enough to make me scared of using it.

Comment: I think it depends on your situation, but I'm no expert either. I think @Barmar's answer should work.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments below my answer, the more significant problem is that you're not setting the variables correctly in the first place. Whether you pass them as parameters or globals is moot until you resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Pass them as arguments to `showPreview`:

```
function showPreview(coords, imgheight, imgwidth) {
    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $('#preview').css({
        width: Math.round(rx * imgwidth) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * imgheight) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
}

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            var img = new Image;
            img.src = reader.result;

            var imgwidth = img.width;
            var imgheight = img.height;
            console.log(imgwidth);
            console.log(imgheight);

            $('#imgcrop').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.crop').Jcrop({

                onSelect: updateCoords,
                boxWidth: 300,
                boxHeight: 300,
                onChange: function(coords) {
                    showPreview(coords, imgheight, imgwidth);
                },
                aspectRatio: 1,
                bgOpacity:   .4,
                setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]
            });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the first things I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it log the correct height and width in the `readURL` function?

Comment: So the problem is with setting the variables, not with how they're sent from one function to the other.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: You probably need to do all this stuff from the image's onload handler, not the reader's.